# SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" on using Fetch in reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs, post, fetch

I am getting above mentioned error on trying to retrieve the JSON response from Fetch API. For some reason it works with 2 API's out of 4, but not for the rest 2. I do not see any difference on Front end code in retrieving the response. Please have a look into below code:

I am not sure what's incorrect here:

```
 async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let responseArray = [];
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let url = "https://api_sports/api/developSports/?";
    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("destIds", this.state.destID);
    form.append("destInfo", this.state.infoID);
    form.append("destPostal", this.state.postID);

    // Figure out the way to append the data in form
    await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: form,
      headers: { "Authorization": `Token ${token}` },
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    }).then((results) => {
      return results.json()
    }).then(response => {
      console.log("Actual Response: ", response)
      if (response.status === 204) {
        console.log("Response 204: ", response)
        this.setState({ alertMessage: "Success" })
      }
     else if (response.status === "error") {
        console.log("Expected Error : ", response);
        responseArray.push(response.messages);
        this.setState({
            alertMessage: "IPError",
            rangeArray: responseArray[0]
        });
    }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error ", err);
    })
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you verified that the API is actually returning, what you expect?

Comment: yes, the API is returning 204 status which means success, but the 204 - is an HTTP response. Is there someway I can check for both HTTP and JSON response?

Comment: I was referring to the actual content. Maybe try using `response.text()` to see the it. I'm guessing that the server is misconfigured and you are actually receiving an HTML error page.

Comment: For somereason, on trying text() method, it does not show anything on success response. Also, the backend API response looks fine: 
return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=204)

Comment: Is the above code run from the same domain as the API? If not, does the API set the proper CORS headers?

Comment: I do not understand "domain". But yes CORS Middleware header is set in the backend too.

Comment: The API response seems fine to me, because its built in the same way for other status codes too and they work, except 204 return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'messages': message}, status=550) -- working return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=204) --json.parse() error

Answer (score 0):

Please check you API response once Because your API is not returning a JSON object that why you are getting this error. It may be a malformed JSON in response.

Comment: The API response seems fine to me, because its built in the same way for other status codes too and they work, except 204
return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'messages': message}, status=550) -- working
return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=204) --json.parse() error

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding below code, splitting the response into two (HTTP and JSON)

```
await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: form,
      headers: { "Authorization": `Token ${token}` },
      "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
    }).then((results) => {
      if (results.status === 204) {
        this.setState({ alertMessage: "Success" })
      }
      else {
        return results.json()
          .then(response => {
            if (response.status === "error") {
              responseArray.push(response.messages);
              this.setState({
                alertMessage: "Failure",
                rangeArray: responseArray[0]
              });
            }
          });
      }
    })
```

Thank you everyone!

Comment: you should accept this answer if it does indeed resolve your issue.